# Capturing the effects of SetConsoleTextAttribute when redirected through a Pipe?

Tags: c, winapi, colors, pipe, redirect

I've redirected `stdout` of a child process spawned with `CreateProcess` to a pipe.  It works fine except that, as far as I can tell, no information about color changes are coming through.  The child process is using `SetConsoleTextAttribute` to change the text color--is it possible to detect this through the pipe and, if so, how?

I'm ultimately displaying the output in a `RichEdit` control and I would like to capture the color information if at all possible.

This is in C with the Win32 API on XP and Vista.

Comment: `SetConsoleTextAttribute` only effects the calling code's console, and has nothing to do with streams or pipes. Just like you wouldn't expect pipes to tell you if a window was maximized, it won't tell you if it's done this. That said, I'm sure there's a workaround. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use ReadConsoleOutput (and/or related ones) found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(VS.85).aspx.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a work around...its old and not-used much!

1. Use Ansi.Sys and load that.
2. Whenever you output a text to the console, by using the Escape sequence, you can set a color around the text.
3. Then parse the escape sequences into the equivalent for RichText Colors.

The escape sequences are standard [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). [Here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/UserTips/CommandPrompt/CommandInterpreterAnsiSupport.html) is how to add support for ANSI.SYS into the console. And [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101875) is the official KB from Microsoft on how to do this.

For an example:

```
printf("\x1b[33;43Yellow on Blue\x1b[0\n");
```

Now, parse the bit after the `\x1b[`, 33 is yellow foreground, and 43 is blue background, then look up the relevant color for that and set it in the RichTextBox..

**Note:** `\x1b[0` turns off the attribute.

**Edit:** This may not be the best solution as that's for legacy NTVDM's 16bit DOS command.com under XP or later. But however, I found another link to '[ansicon](http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/index.html)' here which is for pure cmd.exe 32bit console, with ANSI support.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I seriously doubt this would work.  You would use ANSI.SYS to get escape strings sent to stdout to produce SetConsoleTextAttribute() calls.  Not the other way around.

Comment: @nobugz: You're 100% correct there...oh.....dang... I realized what you meant.. :(