# Delphi: how to capture COLORED output of the CONSOLE application?

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg

I saw several way to capture the output of the started console application. But all they were "monochrome" solution, for example FFMPEG may produce coloured output. How to catch the color?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is here. What output are you trying to capture? What "started application"? What does "catch the color" even mean? Please [edit] your question to provide more details and make it more specific. As it is now, it will probably be closed pretty quickly.

Comment: ups, yes, I forgot to say Im talking about "console" applications

Comment: Do you mean color output made by escape sequences when ANSI.sys is loaded, as in the old DOS days (http://www.pcxt-micro.com/ansi.html, not sure this is possible at all in a modern console Windows)?. You can probably catch the escape sequences together with the regular output, but I'm not sure if that's any good. You'd have to interpret the escape sequences in the captured character stream. That's a lot of work and whether that's useful depends on what you plan to do with it.

Comment: It looks as if you are confusing the video stream of the Windows environment (which you can catch 'into' a video), and the character console output of the app (to stdout).

Comment: @Jan: Actually, Ansi.sys color functionality is available in a command window now. Open one, and type `color 9e`, for instance (you can use `color 07` to revert to the defaults, or simply `color` with no parameters). `color /?` gives you the color combinations (0-F, foreground/background).

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211567/capturing-the-effects-of-setconsoletextattribute-when-redirected-through-a-pipe . However, the accepted answer there suggests using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684965(v=vs.85).aspx, without explaining how to practically implement that (stream buffer versus console screen buffer).

Answer (score 2):

You wil have to hook all of the console output functions (say, WriteConsoleOutput; see MSDN Library for the list of them) to access the process' screen buffer, then pass the intercepted output to your application via shared memory or a pipe. AFAIK, there's no other way to get access to console output handles of another application.